# How to load an Ektron widget's global data programmatically?

Tags: c#, ektron

I've got an Ektron widget that has global settings and local settings which can override them. I need a way to programmatically read the global settings in the widget itself because depending on user input I need to reset the values to what is stored globally.

**Is there an API method to read the global settings of a widget?** I saw this question that shows how to read the instance-level settings by getting what is stored in the page XML, but that doesn't give me what is stored at the global level.

[Load Ektron widget by ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12579314/load-ektron-widget-by-id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this by using the `Ektron.Cms.Widget.IWidgetTypeModel.FindByID()` method.

```
var widgetTypeModel = new Ektron.Cms.Widget.WidgetTypeModel();
Ektron.Cms.Widget.WidgetTypeData widgetTypeData = null;
widgetTypeModel.FindByControlURL("Widget.ascx", out widgetTypeData);
```